# What's an idiomatic way to get the final value of the iterator function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, iterator, generator, yield

I have a pretty complicated function that describes some iterative process. It looks something like this (I've a lot of code that is irrelevant to the question):

```
function* functionName(
    config: Config,
    poolSize: number
): Generator<[State, Step], boolean, void> {
    /* ... */

    for (const step of someOtherProcess()) {
        /* ... */

        yield [state, step]

        switch (stateType) {
            case StateType.Start:
                if (/* ... */) {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true
                }

            case StateType.Invalid:
                return false
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

It does three things: (1) emulates some process, (2) provides information of every step of the process (as you can see in the line with `yield`), and (3) provides an end result when the process is complete. Obviously, (3) and (2) are direct logical consequences of (1), that's why I perform both tasks in one function.

However, while some users of the function care about each step (2), some others only care about the end result (3).

For now, I use this:

```
const generator = functionName(config, poolSize)
let result
while (!(result = generator.next()).done) {}
return result.value as boolean
```

Is there some more idiomatic and simple way to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just add an option?

```
function* functionName(
    config: Config,
    poolSize: number,
    yieldSteps = true
): Generator<[State, Step], boolean, void> {
    /* ... */

    for (const step of someOtherProcess()) {
        /* ... */

        if (yieldSteps) { yield [state, step] }

        switch (stateType) {
            case StateType.Start:
                if (/* ... */) {
                    return false
                } else {
                    return true
                }

            case StateType.Invalid:
                return false
        }
    }

    return false
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That solves my problem in this particular case, but I'm still curious, what if that generator function was a part of a third-party API?